# Character set mismatch oracle Error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT QUOTE_CREATION.*,
       CASE
          WHEN (SUBSTR (QUOTE_CREATION."PO_number", 1, 3)) = 'ARA'
          THEN
             'TE161938'
          WHEN (SUBSTR (QUOTE_CREATION."PO_number", 1, 3)) = 'HH-'
          THEN
             'TE161302'
          WHEN (SUBSTR (QUOTE_CREATION."PO_number", 1, 3)) = 'SMT'
          THEN
             'TE161101'
          WHEN (SUBSTR (QUOTE_CREATION."PO_number", 1, 3)) = 'AYP'
          THEN
             'TE108812'
          WHEN (SUBSTR (QUOTE_CREATION."PO_number", 1, 3)) = 'DKR'
          THEN
             'TE160895'
          ELSE
             QUOTE_CREATION."Created_By"
       END
          AS CORRECT_USER_ID
  FROM CCO.QUOTE_CREATION QUOTE_CREATION
```

But when i try to run the query I'm getting an error "Character set mismatch" at the " ELSE '' " part of the CASE expression. Can someone suggest where I'm doing it wrong?

Thank you
santhosha

Comment: @Indoknight This is perfectly valid syntax in Oracle and is used when you need to specify the name that contains lower case letters.

Comment: What is the data type of 'Created_By'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QUOTE_CREATION."Created_By" is probably `NVARCHAR2`

Try something like this:

```
SELECT QUOTE_CREATION.*,
       CASE
          WHEN (SUBSTR (QUOTE_CREATION."PO_number", 1, 3)) = 'ARA'
          THEN
             N'TE161938'
          WHEN (SUBSTR (QUOTE_CREATION."PO_number", 1, 3)) = 'HH-'
          THEN
             N'TE161302'
          WHEN (SUBSTR (QUOTE_CREATION."PO_number", 1, 3)) = 'SMT'
          THEN
             N'TE161101'
          WHEN (SUBSTR (QUOTE_CREATION."PO_number", 1, 3)) = 'AYP'
          THEN
             N'TE108812'
          WHEN (SUBSTR (QUOTE_CREATION."PO_number", 1, 3)) = 'DKR'
          THEN
             N'TE160895'
          ELSE
             QUOTE_CREATION."Created_By"
       END
          AS CORRECT_USER_ID
  FROM CCO.QUOTE_CREATION QUOTE_CREATION
```

Comment: Also if you don't mind could you please explain why we insert "N" before our criteria

Comment: I guess it's a hint to Oracle that the string which is following is of type `NCHAR` (Unicode character set), otherwise it probably thinks it's `CHAR`.